# Who is establishing the big tent cities by the sea in Gaza?

Tags: israel, united-nations, refugees, gaza, 2023-israel-hamas-war

According to a former Mossad "division chief", Rami Igra, [interviewed on CNN](https://www.newarab.com/news/cnn-silent-ex-mossad-head-claims-all-gaza-hamas) the population from Khan Yunis is asked to move by the sea, where "big tent cities are being established". Who is establishing these?

FWTW, I was able to find out that about a month ago, the UN [provided](https://www.972mag.com/gaza-tent-city-khan-younis/) some 100 (small) tents "providing temporary shelter for around 800 people". That seems hardly enough for a city. Is the UN stepping up their efforts in that regard now?

OTOH, an opinion piece in WaPo by David Ignatius also says/confirms there is a "planned refugee camp" in Al-Mawasi, by the sea. However, this piece says that Israel (not the UN) is going to build that

> To care for Palestinians who have fled the battle zones, Israel plans to create a vast tent city for refugees at Al-Mawasi, on the coast just north of the Gazan border with Egypt.

Have (current) Israeli officials (not just former ones) confirmed this plan?

The WSJ even talked about that tent city plan on [Nov 11](https://www.wsj.com/livecoverage/israel-hamas-war-gaza-strip-2023-11-08/card/israel-says-it-has-sent-tents-for-people-displaced-by-fighting-in-gaza-LntqRj7uV4QUEhKCn9vr), at least in terms of Israel having sent the tents already. Has anything materialized on the ground though (in Al-Mawasi)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frame challenge. I wouldn't read the formulation 'tent cities are established' as claiming that anyone formaly provides a bunch of tents and organizes them into a nice tent city. It can mean that but it can also just refer to the result you get when you put a large number of people in some open air area.

The refugees themselves will try to mark off spots for their piles of stuff and cover them with whatever blankets they have. One can call the result a 'tent city' being established by refugees.

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comment, this is looking at a very short term perspective. If nobody provides water, food, basic sanitation and medical care within say 2 weeks a significant proportion of the refugees in there will die. Unfortunately this doesn't imply someone has started building this tent city right now.

Comment: The organization of such a *city* housing thousands of people usually requires more than just tents to live - distributing land parcels, building routes, organizing food supply and sanitation services, providing medical care. Anyhow, the above seems more like a comment than an answer (no offense intended.)

Comment: @RogerV. If there is a food supply, sanitation services medical care and so on, then yes someone has to organize that. I'm just not sure any of these things actually are there, at least in the beginning.

Comment: @quarange if there were none, there would not be a *city* - they would either move on in search for food/shelter or start dying from epidemic diseases, resort to cannibalism, engage in gang violence, etc. Things get ugly pretty quickly - see, e.g., what happened in [Nazino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazino_tragedy)

Comment: @RogerV. The Palestineans are stuck inside the Gaza strip. With Israel calling for the evacuation of Khan Yunis in the south of the strip there isn't really any place for them to go. This is looking at a very short time perspective, see edit.

Comment: @quarange I am not disputing the gravity of the situation - just pointing that unmanaged tent city is highly improbable. Without food an sanitation the problems, like those I mentioned above, begin within a matter of a few days. We are talking about thousands people here.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently there's not much agreement or details on that [thus far](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-67518819):

> In a post on social media on Thursday, Avichay Adraee, the IDF's spokesman for the Arabic media, told Gazans al-Mawasi would provide "the appropriate conditions to protect your loved ones." [...]
>
> **Israeli officials say it will be up to aid agencies to make sure help reaches al-Mawasi from the Rafah crossing, more than 10km away.** They haven't said how this will work in practice. [...]
>
> Any attempt to accommodate hundreds of thousands of displaced people, in an area seemingly lacking in essential infrastructure - there are no hospitals - will present the UN with a mammoth humanitarian challenge, including the setting up of emergency shelter, most likely tents. [...]
>
> But on 16 November, a statement by the heads of 18 UN agencies and NGOs involved in providing assistance to Palestinian civilians appeared to reject Israel's plans outright.
>
> "We will not participate in the establishment of any 'safe zone' in Gaza that is set up without the agreement of all the parties," it said.
>
> UN officials say the parties include Israel, Hamas and the Palestinian Authority, based in the West Bank.
>
> Without mentioning al-Mawasi by name, the 16 November statement warned that Israel's unilateral proposals could put many lives at risk. [...] One of the signatories, Dr Tedros Ghebreyesus, director-general of the World Health Organisation, called the plans "a recipe for disaster". [...]
>
> Israeli officials say Hamas is to blame and seem unfazed by the dangers. Al-Mawasi, they say, is the one area Israeli forces have undertaken not to attack. [...] "People in Israel don't like the situation where people in Gaza are somewhere in al-Mawasi, under the rain of winter, which is coming," says retired Maj Gen Yaacov Amidror, a former Israeli national security adviser. "But what is the alternative? If someone has an idea how to destroy Hamas without it, please tell us." [...]
>
> With winter looming, Israel gearing up for the decisive next phase of its campaign, and **no agreement on how to deal with the civilian population**, Gaza's long agony looks set to continue. Perhaps even to get worse.

Comment: That seems to confirm what I feared in my answer. Israel is not providing anything and at best promises not to interfere if someone else puts up a tent city.

Comment: I would of course note that “winter” in Gaza is 17C during the day / 10C during the night. Based off my own experience camping this is easy to deal with. I would be a lot more worried about summer time.

Comment: @JonathanReez: looking at the pop density in some of the recent photos https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-67646964 it might be even warmer. Like a flock of sheep. Needs some delousing though, according to that report.

Comment: Look, I'm not saying it doesn't suck for the Gaza residents, but "winter looming" in the article is a bit hyperbolic.

Answer (score 3):

**[IDF instructions on Gaza refuge zones cruel ‘mirage’, say aid agencies](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/dec/07/idf-israel-gaza-refuge-zones-cruel-mirage-say-aid-agencies)** - *Those who have fled to ‘humanitarian zone’ in south-west Gaza bemoan total lack of shelter and barely any food*:

> Instructions from Israeli forces telling Gaza civilians where to seek refuge and humanitarian relief have given contradictory recommendations, while aid agencies and Palestinians who have heeded them describe the offer of safety as a cruel “mirage” amid an intensifying military campaign.
>
> Those who have fled to a “humanitarian zone” declared by the Israeli Defense Forces (IDF) at **al-Mawasi, a Bedouin settlement on sand dunes** in the south-west corner of the Gaza Strip, have **depicted a desperate scene with no shelter and barely any food**. **The IDF, meanwhile, has not ruled out bombing the area**, claiming that rockets were fired from there, most recently on Wednesday.
>
> ... **the IDF has been inconsistent in recommending al-Mawasi as a safe space**. Maps and instructions distributed recently ... with orange arrows showing how civilians should move ... The arrows have changed direction as circumstances have changed in the past few days, but none of them specifically pointed towards al-Mawasi, nor was the 14 sq km coastal area mentioned in the accompanying text.
>
> ... Al-Mawasi was however shown in a presentation by the IDF to the international press on Thursday. It appeared as a grey area on a map of southern Gaza, labelled as a “humanitarian zone”.
>
> ... Pictures of al-Mawasi published by Sky News showed **flimsy improvised shelters erected over an expanse of sand strewn with rubbish**.
>
> “It is not possible to concentrate large numbers of civilians in such tiny slivers of land without exacerbating an already dire humanitarian catastrophe,” **Alexandra Saieh, the head of humanitarian policy at Save the Children International, warned**. “People are in overcrowded shelters in makeshift tents. There is no access to clean water, there are crumbling sanitation facilities. **We’ve heard of children starving in the so-called ‘safe zone’ of al-Mawasi**.”
>
> The UN Relief and Works Agency (UNRWA) said in a statement: “***The UN is not involved in this and has underlined repeatedly that unilaterally declared ‘safe zones’ are not safe at all. Nowhere in Gaza is safe***.”

*(All emphasis above have been added by me, and is not in the original source)*.

Comment: This seems to be focusing entirely on the conditions at al-Mawasi, and not who actually *built* al-Mawasi (and would thus be responsible for said conditions), which is what the question is actually asking. The source briefly mentions that Israel "declared" a humanitarian zone there, but not whether Israel actually built it, or whether it was there beforehand.

Comment: @F1Krazy That is the point, nobody actually build anything in al-Mawasi. What you see there is what you get if no one feels they are responsible for building anything thre. Whatever is there is what the refugees brought with them and established themselves.